# Trouble with retrieving certificate information in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to build a dashboard to retrieve certificate information on all our servers, but I'm struggling with the powershell object handling.  I believe it's the way objects are getting passed inside and outside a loop.  I have 3 iterations of my code.

In the first, all certificates are retrieved, but the FriendlyName is blanked out on every object:

```
$serverCert = $null
$servers=get-adcomputer -filter { ( OperatingSystem -like '*server*') -AND ( Name -notlike '*-DT0094' ) } | sort Name
foreach ( $server in $servers ) { 
    $ServerName=$server.Name
    $ServerName="$ServerName.DOMAINSUFFIX"
    $serverCert += Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ServerName -Scriptblock { 
        return $(Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\My)
    }
}
$serverCert | Select-Object PSComputerName, Thumbprint, FriendlyName, NotAfter, @{N="Template";E={($_.Extensions | ?{$_.oid.Friendlyname -match "Certificate Template Information"}).Format(0) -replace "(.+)?=(.+)\((.+)?", '$2'}}, @{N="IssuedBy";E={($_.IssuerName.Name -split ',*..=')[1]}}, @{N="Subject";E={($_.Subject -split ',*..=')[1]}} | Sort Thumbprint | Format-Table -Wrap
```

In this iteration, the Extensions come through like this:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS> $serverCert[0] | Select-Object -Property Extensions

Extensions
----------
{System.Security.Cryptography.Oid, System.Security.Cryptography.Oid}
```

In the second, I solved this by explicitly passing the FriendlyName through as a new property called "Description"...unfortunately, now the Template doesn't display:

```
$serverCert = $null
$servers=get-adcomputer -filter { ( OperatingSystem -like '*server*') -AND ( Name -notlike '*-DT0094' ) } | sort Name
foreach ( $server in $servers ) { 
    $ServerName=$server.Name
    $ServerName="$ServerName.DOMAINSUFFIX"
    $serverCert += Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ServerName -Scriptblock { 
        return $(Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\My | Select-Object *, @{N="Description";E={$_.FriendlyName}})
    }
}
$serverCert | Select-Object PSComputerName, Thumbprint, Description, NotAfter, @{N="Template";E={($_.Extensions | ?{$_.oid.Friendlyname -match "Certificate Template Information"}).Format(0) -replace "(.+)?=(.+)\((.+)?", '$2'}}, @{N="IssuedBy";E={($_.IssuerName.Name -split ',*..=')[1]}}, @{N="Subject";E={($_.Subject -split ',*..=')[1]}} | Sort Thumbprint | Format-Table -Wrap
```

In this iteration, the Extensions come through like this, and I can't get template name to display:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS> $serverCert[0] | Select-Object -Property Extensions

Extensions
----------
{System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509EnhancedKeyUsageExtension, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyUsageExtension}
```

Now the third.  This time I try to pass the template information forward as a property like the "Description."  Problem is, the template information doesn't come through clearly; rather than the friendly name, other info is displayed.

```
$serverCert = $null
$servers=get-adcomputer -filter { ( OperatingSystem -like '*server*') -AND ( Name -notlike '*-DT0094' ) } | sort Name
foreach ( $server in $servers ) { 
    $ServerName=$server.Name
    $ServerName="$ServerName.DOMAINSUFFIX"
    $serverCert += Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ServerName -Scriptblock { 
        return $(Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\My | Select-Object *, @{N="Description";E={$_.FriendlyName}}, @{N="Template";E={($_.Extensions | ?{$_.oid.Friendlyname -match "Certificate Template Information"}).Format(0) -replace "(.+)?=(.+)\((.+)?", '$2'}})
    }
}
$serverCert | Select-Object PSComputerName, Thumbprint, Description, NotAfter, Template, @{N="IssuedBy";E={($_.IssuerName.Name -split ',*..=')[1]}}, @{N="Subject";E={($_.Subject -split ',*..=')[1]}} | Sort Thumbprint | Format-Table -Wrap
```

Template information for some certificates (I can't correlate on template, OS version...anything) looks like this:

Template=1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.8.16245382.12313948.10571683.3565079.1665071.100.15924968.15384388, Major Version Number=100, Minor Version Number=4

I'm stumped.  I am still getting comfortable in powershell, but I don't understand object manipulation well enough to know how to fix this.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I don't have time at the moment to parse your code and write up a proper answer, but look at this script I have as a Github gist: https://gist.github.com/bender-the-greatest/3e2f6e6d606eebaeedbacd8722e52396. Specifically, the `findWinRMCert` function, where I find a certificate created from a template named `WinRM`. You can `ctrl+f` to find that function name.

Answer (score 2):

I think FriendlyName not getting returned in your first iteration has to do with the way PowerShell is deserializing data when the *-ComputerName* parameter is used.

In your first iteration, try changing this line:

```
return $(Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\My)
```

to:

```
return $(Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\My | Select-Object *)
```

To illustrate the issue, run these three commands, which you would expect to all include the same object properties.  Note that FriendlyName is only included in the output of the first two commands:

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { gci Cert:\LocalMachine\My } | Select-Object FriendlyName
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { gci Cert:\LocalMachine\My | Select-Object * }  -ComputerName . | Select-Object FriendlyName
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { gci Cert:\LocalMachine\My }  -ComputerName . | Select-Object FriendlyName
```

Edit: This is how I might do it:

```
Function Get-Cert-Info($ComputerName) {
  Invoke-Command -Computer $ComputerName -ScriptBlock {
    $certs = Get-ChildItem cert:\localmachine\my

    foreach($cert in $certs) {
      [pscustomobject]@{
        ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
        Thumbprint = $cert.Thumbprint
        Description = $cert.FriendlyName
        TemplateName = $(
          $Template = $cert.Extensions | Where-Object { $_.oid.FriendlyName -match "Certificate Template Information" }
          if($Template) { 
            ($Template.Format(0) -split "\(")[0] -replace "Template=", ""
          }
        )
        SAN=$(
          try {
            $cert.Extensions | Where-Object {$_.Oid.FriendlyName -eq "subject alternative name"} | ForEach {
              $SANString = "{0}" -f $_.Format(0)
              $SANS = $SANString -split ','

              foreach($SAN in $SANS) {
                ($SAN -split "=")[1]
              }
            }  
          } catch {
            "n/a"
          }
        )
        IssuedBy=$(($cert.IssuerName.Name -split ',')[0] -replace 'CN=', '')
        Subject=$(($cert.Subject -split ',')[0] -replace 'CN=', '')
        NotAfter=$cert.NotAfter       
      }  
    }
  }
}

$servers=get-adcomputer -filter { ( OperatingSystem -like '*server*') -AND ( Name -notlike '*-DT0094' ) } | sort Name

foreach ( $server in $servers ) { 
  Get-Cert-Info -ComputerName $server.Name
}
```

Comment: So,  you're right that fixes the FriendlyName...and triggers the flip of the Extensions object types back to the one in the 2nd block!  I don't understand why specifying the export of the Extensions property flips its type.

Comment: To avoid the serialization issues, try performing all of your object property access and string manipulation directly inside of your scriptblock.  I had to reformat your code a little bit to wrap my brain around it (sorry about that), but check out my edit.  Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for this tip. It really helped

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get the template name though, but lookup would fail, so I did something akin to a replace when I got the ID:

```
# Get all certificates from all servers
clear-host
$serverCert = $null
ipconfig /flushdns
$servers=get-adcomputer -filter { OperatingSystem -like '*server*' } | sort Name
foreach ( $server in $servers ) { 
    $ServerName=$server.Name
    $ServerName="$ServerName.DOMAINSUFFIX"
    $serverCert += Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ServerName -Scriptblock { 
        return $(Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\My | Select-Object *, @{N="Description";E={$_.FriendlyName}}, @{N="TemplateName";E={($_.Extensions | ?{$_.oid.Friendlyname -match "Certificate Template Information"}).Format(0) -replace "(.+)?=(.+)\((.+)?", '$2' -replace 'Template=', '' -replace '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.8.16245382.12313948.10571683.3565079.1665071.100.15924968.15384388.*', 'SCCM Client Certificate' -replace '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.8.16245382.12313948.10571683.3565079.1665071.100.9941395.14900143.*','IIS Web Servers' -replace '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.8.16245382.12313948.10571683.3565079.1665071.100.1979823.4984146.*','WSUS Web Server Certificate'}})
    }
}
$serverCert | Select-Object PSComputerName, Thumbprint, Description, NotAfter, TemplateName, @{N="IssuedBy";E={($_.IssuerName.Name -split ',*..=')[1]}}, @{N="Subject";E={($_.Subject -split ',*..=')[1]}} | Sort NotAfter, PSComputerName | Format-Table -Wrap
```